# Why creating a block that has slightly higher difficulty can beat out any possible forks?

Tags: timestamp, difficulty

It is said that
"The use of (block_timestamp - parent_timestamp) // 10 (* now 9)as the main input variable rather than the time difference directly serves to maintain the coarse-grained nature of the algorithm, preventing an excessive incentive to set the timestamp difference to exactly 1 in order to create a block that has slightly higher difficulty and that will thus be guaranteed to beat out any possible forks."

How to understand that? What is the benefit for miners to set the timestamp interval to be 1s? Why creating a block that has slightly higher difficulty can beat out any possible forks?

Comment: Hi there. Do you have a source for the first paragraph?

Comment: Looks like it comes from https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2.

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.md